# Not able to to filter messages received using condition attribute in Spring Cloud Stream @StreamListener annotation

Tags: events, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to create a event based system for communicating between services using Apache Kafka as Messaging system and Spring Cloud Stream Kafka.

I have written my Receiver class methods as below,

```
    @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT, condition = "headers['eventType']=='EmployeeCreatedEvent'")
    public void handleEmployeeCreatedEvent(@Payload String payload) {
        logger.info("Received EmployeeCreatedEvent: " + payload);
    }
```

This method is specifically to catch for messages or events related to EmployeeCreatedEvent.

```
    @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT, condition = "headers['eventType']=='EmployeeTransferredEvent'")
    public void handleEmployeeTransferredEvent(@Payload String payload) {
        logger.info("Received EmployeeTransferredEvent: " + payload);
    }
```

This method is specifically to catch for messages or events related to EmployeeTransferredEvent.

```
    @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)
    public void handleDefaultEvent(@Payload String payload) {
        logger.info("Received payload: " + payload);
    }
```

This is the default method.

When I run the application, I am not able to see the methods annoated with condition attribute being called. I only see the **handleDefaultEvent** method being called.

I am sending a message to this Receiver Application from the Sending/Source App  using the below CustomMessageSource class as below,

```
@Component
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class CustomMessageSource {
    @Autowired
    private Source source;                


    public void  sendMessage(String payload,String eventType) {
        Message<String> myMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload)
                .setHeader("eventType", eventType)
                .build();
        source.output().send(myMessage);

     }

}
```

I am calling the method from my controller in Source App as below,

```
customMessageSource.sendMessage("Hello","EmployeeCreatedEvent");
```

The customMessageSource instance is autowired as below,

```
@Autowired
CustomMessageSource customMessageSource;
```

Basicaly, I would like to filter messages received by the Sink/Receiver application and handle them accordingly.

For this I have used the @StreamListener annotation with condition attribute to simulate the behaviour of handling different events.

I am using **Spring Cloud Stream Chelsea.SR2** version.

Can someone help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the headers are not propagated. Make sure you include the custom headers in `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers` http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-stream-docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_binder_properties .

Comment: Thanks for responding. But, I don't get your response. I am explicitly constructing the message with payload and headers as received as input. I am not sure why I should include custom headers in configuration file.

Comment: Spring cloud stream doesn't propagate custom headers by default. This setting will tell the producer application that we should.

Comment: Kafka (currently) has no notion of headers; we have to embed them in the data; hence the opt-in approach, to avoid adding unnecessary data.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense now.